# "Читабельность" длинных фраз в современном обществе

Tags: стилистика

Помогите, пожалуйста, развеять сомнения. 
Люблю составлять длинные фразы. Но, говорят, что современная молодёжь не умеет читать фразы длиннее трёх-четырёх слов. Мозг не воспринимает написанное. Поэтому на письме дроблю их как можно короче. 
Но читатели в возрасте осуждают подобную практику. Им наоборот - трудно читать разделённые точкой предложения, в которых продолжается одна мысль или повествование. Выходит, дробление по мелким предложениям тоже иногда вредит?
Вот и сегодня, столкнулся с длинной фразой, которую вроде бы нужно дробить. На мой взгляд она интересна и закончена. Но не тяжело ли такое читать?

Как всё-таки лучше? Так:
"У Элемунда, тащившего на себе их драгоценную находку, руки были заняты ношей, поэтому Сигурду приходилось одной рукой держаться за плечо их поводыря, а другой – поддерживать бывшего ландскнехта под ручку, словно даму, шествующую на высоченных каблуках, до сих пор модных во фриландском Хойхеле"

либо так:
" У Элемунда, тащившего на себе их драгоценную находку, руки были заняты ношей. Поэтому Сигурду приходилось одной рукой держаться за плечо их поводыря, а другой – поддерживать бывшего ландскнехта под ручку. Словно даму, шествующую на высоченных каблуках, до сих пор модных во фриландском Хойхеле"?
                                                                                                   (не понимаю, почему у меня в блоге не работает абзац?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> не понимаю, почему у меня в блоге не работает абзац???

Данный вопрос не совсем по тематике сайта, но я отвечу. Разделение абзацев вертикальными отступами является общепринятой практикой в современных браузерах. Если Вы не хотите вставлять лишнюю строку, можете использовать тег <p>. [Здесь](https://puzzleweb.ru/html/5_paragraphs.php#a2) можете посмотреть подробнее. (Кстати, большинство участников этого сайта вполне понимают одиночный знак вопроса. Для усиления экспрессии ставьте, пожалуйста, общепринятый знак "?!")

По поводу других Ваших вопросов.

Это неправда, что молодёжь не умеет читать фразы длиннее трёх-четырёх слов. Но в длинных предложениях очень важна правильная пунктуация, иначе следить за смыслом предложения действительно сложно. Например, в Вашем вопросе пунктуационные ошибки встречаются даже в коротких предложениях.

Да, дробление на слишком простые и короткие предложения иногда вредит.

Предложенная фраза мне понравилась бы больше без самой последней части:

**У Элемунда, тащившего на себе их драгоценную находку, руки были заняты ношей, поэтому Сигурду приходилось одной рукой держаться за плечо их поводыря, а другой – поддерживать бывшего ландскнехта под ручку, словно даму, шествующую на высоченных каблуках.**

Вполне возможно, что последняя часть важна в определённом контексте, но мне сложно представить такой контекст.

Comment: Пунктуационные ошибки - это моя беда. Приходится их исправлять в текстах годами! И это не преувеличение. Не только потому, что я ставлю знаки препинания "на слух", но ещё и потому, что переделываю фразы по пятьдесят раз. И запятые из старых вариантов (а иногда и падежи), перекочёвывают в новые варианты. Помогать с редактированием теперь некому, к сожалению. Самооправдался. :) <p> Последняя часть предложения призвана только лишь добавить реальности в мир, где происходит действие. Может быть вы и прАвы - дьявол в деталях. Вполне возможно, что эта деталь лишняя.

Comment: По поводу тега HTML. Что-то не работает. В редакторе только визуальный стиль и он не понимает HTML.

Comment: @romandc Прошу извинить, если был не достаточно тактичен — приходится отрабатывать аватарский имидж :)  Тег абзаца не будет работать в комментариях, но в окнах вопросов и ответов он работает (я специально проверял).

Comment: Спасибо огромное за критику! Без критики гордыня замучает, и прогресса никакого не будет. Насчёт тега - была у меня такая мысль. Но недодуманная. :)

Comment: Кстати, ещё, насчёт последней части фразы. Даже если эту часть придётся удалить, всё равно в ней был смысл! Придумывать названия и имена - это довольно сложный процесс. Но теперь, рождённый в этой фразе город Хойхель неплохо впишется в здешний мир. :) høj hæl - "высокий каблук" по-норвежски.

Comment: Хорошо, я не спорю. Тогда скажу, что полное предложение выглядит вполне нормально. Во всяком случае лучше его дроблёного варианта.

Comment: Ок! Оставляем этот вариант! Ещё раз - огромное спасибо! Но самое главное - теперь надо опять пересматривать все свои тексты! Уже с другой точки зрения. :( :)

Answer (score 0):

Второй вариант читать тяжело. Но не потому что в нем предложения короче, а потому что нельзя просто поставив точек в длинном сложном предложении получить несколько коротких. Нужно еще и текст изменять. К примеру, ваше самое последнее "предложение" ("Словно даму...") вообще предложением не является.

Answer (score 0):

Поставив точку вместо запятой вы фразу короче не делаете. Грамматика подчиняется мысли и отражает её. Первый вариант безусловно лучше, так как предложение должно выражать относительно законченную мысль, не не пойми что.

Если вы хотите сделать фразу менее громоздкой, то её надо переделывать. Как именно подсказать не могу, так как вне контекста непонятно сколько в этом предложении идут людей.

Comment: Три человека путешествуют в подземелье, в абсолютной темноте. И из этих троих - один наделён способностью хорошо ориентироваться в полном мраке. Им приходится идти гуськом, как раньше ходили слепые - положив руку или посох друг-другу на плечо. Но у одного из этой троицы руки заняты. И тому, кто идёт в середине, приходится держать и того и другого, чтобы никто не потерялся. Спасибо за подсказку - буду колдовать над первым вариантом.